# Используя списки, стек, очередь: определить минимальный по сумме уплаченных взяток допустимый порядок получения подписей для лицензии и стоимость

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Нужно в программе на С++ с использованием списков, стека и/или очереди написать программу, вот условие:

Есть министерство из N чиновников, где N натуральное число. У каждого из чиновников могут быть как подчиненные, так и начальники, причем справедливы правила: подчиненные моего подчиненного мои подчиненные, начальники моего начальника - мои начальники, мой начальник не есть мой подчиненный, у каждого чиновника не более одного непосредственного начальника.
Для того чтобы получить лицензию на вывоз меди необходимо получить подпись 1-ого чиновника - начальника всех чиновников. Проблема осложняется тем, что каждый чиновник, вообще говоря, может потребовать "визы", т.е. подписи некоторых своих непосредственных подчиненных и взятку - известное количество долларов. Для каждого чиновника известен непустой список возможных наборов "виз" и соответствующая каждому набору взятка. Пустой набор означает, что данный чиновник не требует виз в данном случае. Чиновник ставит свою подпись лишь после того, как ему представлены все подписи одного из наборов "виз" и уплачена соответствующая взятка.
Необходимо определить и вывести минимальный по сумме уплаченных взяток допустимый порядок получения подписей для лицензии и стоимость.

Я написала, но она ругается на строки 40 и 67 на n. Может кто знает и подскажет, как исправить и правильно я написала программу или нет.

Вот программа, которую я написала

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Структура, представляющая чиновника
struct Official {
    int boss; // id начальника
    bool signed_; // подписана ли уже его подпись
    int bribe; // взятка, которую он требует
    // Структура, представляющая визу
    struct Visa {
        bool signed_; // подписана ли уже виза
        int bribe; // взятка, которую требует виза
        Visa* next; // указатель на следующую визу в списке
        Visa(bool signed_, int bribe, Visa* next = nullptr)
            : signed_(signed_), bribe(bribe), next(next) {}
    };
    Visa* visas; // список виз, которые требует чиновник
    Official(int boss = 0, bool signed_ = false, int bribe = 0, Visa* visas = nullptr)
        : boss(boss), signed_(signed_), bribe(bribe), visas(visas) {}
};

// Функция для добавления визы в список виз чиновника
void addVisa(Official& official, bool signed_, int bribe) {
    official.visas = new Official::Visa(signed_, bribe, official.visas);
}

// Функция для удаления списка виз чиновника
void deleteVisas(Official& official) {
    while (official.visas != nullptr) {
        Official::Visa* visa = official.visas;
        official.visas = visa->next;
        delete visa;
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n; // Считываем количество чиновников
    Official* officials = new Official[n + 1]; // Создаем динамический массив чиновников
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        int k;
        cin >> k; // Считываем количество виз, которые требует чиновник
        Official official;
        for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
            int m;
            cin >> m; // Считываем количество виз, которые требует текущая виза
            Official::Visa* visas = nullptr;
            for (int l = 0; l < m; ++l) {
                int visa;
                cin >> visa; // Считываем id чиновников, которые могут подписать визу
                visas = new Official::Visa(false, visa, visas);
            }
            int bribe;
            cin >> bribe; // Считываем взятку, которую требует чиновник за подписание визы
            addVisa(official, false, bribe); // Добавляем визу в список виз чиновника
            deleteVisas(official); // Удаляем список виз, если он был создан ранее
            official.visas = visas; // Присваиваем список виз чиновнику
        }
        officials[i] = official; // Добавляем чиновника в массив чиновников
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        int boss;
        cin >> boss; // Считываем id начальника чиновника
        officials[i].boss = boss; // Присваиваем начальника чиновнику
    }
    int* toSign = new int[n + 1]; // Создаем динамический массив для хранения id чиновников, которые нужно подписать
    int top = 0; // Индекс верхнего элемента в массиве toSign
    toSign[top++] = 1; // Добавляем в стек начальника всех чиновников
    int totalBribe = 0; // Общая сумма взяток
    while (top > 0) { // Пока стек не пуст
        int id = toSign[--top]; // Извлекаем из стека верхний элемент
        Official& official = officials[id]; // Получаем ссылку на чиновника
        if (official.signed_) { // Если подпись уже подписана, пропускаем чиновника
            continue;
        }
        bool allVisasSigned = true; // Флаг, указывающий, подписаны ли все визы чиновника
        Official::Visa* visa = official.visas; // Получаем указатель на первую визу в списке виз чиновника
        while (visa != nullptr) { // Пока есть визы в списке
            if (!visa->signed_) { // Если виза еще не подписана, выставляем флаг allVisasSigned в false
                allVisasSigned = false;
                break;
            }
            visa = visa->next; // Переходим к следующей визе
        }
        if (allVisasSigned) { // Если все визы подписаны
            official.signed_ = true; // Подписываем подпись чиновника
            totalBribe += official.bribe; // Добавляем взятку к общей сумме
            if (official.boss != 0) { // Если у чиновника есть начальник, добавляем его в стек
                toSign[top++] = official.boss;
            }
        }
        else { // Если не все визы подписаны
            toSign[top++] = id; // Добавляем чиновника в стек
            visa = official.visas; // Получаем указатель на первую визу в списке виз чиновника
            while (visa != nullptr) { // Пока есть визы
                if (!visa->signed_) { // Если виза еще не подписана
                    Official& visaOfficial = officials[visa->bribe]; // Получаем ссылку на чиновника, который требует взятку за подписание визы
                    if (visaOfficial.signed_) { // Если чиновник уже подписал подпись
                        visa->signed_ = true; // Подписываем визу
                    }
                    else { // Если чиновник еще не подписал подпись
                        toSign[top++] = visa->bribe; // Добавляем чиновника в стек
                    }
                }
                visa = visa->next; // Переходим к следующей визе
            }
        }
    }
    cout << totalBribe << endl; // Выводим общую сумму взяток
    delete[] officials; // Освобождаем память, выделенную под динамический массив чиновников
    delete[] toSign; // Освобождаем память, выделенную под динамический массив id чиновников, которые нужно подписать
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Полный текст ошибки? Где тут строки 40 и 67?

Comment: Отличная попытка для первого вопроса, но как указали выше - очень не хватает полного текста ошибки. Так же вы зря прилепили к вопросу весь свой код. Стоило локализовать проблему, убрать несущественные для её воспроизведения части, чтобы снизить когнитивную нагрузку на отвечающего. В процессе, кстати проблему и решить можно ненароком) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: исправила эти ошибки 40 и 67 строки, но все равно не работает